# What is the numerals style that goes above/below the standard height called, and is there a historic reason behind it?

Tags: numbers, typography

It's often found on Wikipedia in the titles of articles, and here on this site:

> ## 1916

In the example above (if it doesn't render correctly, say you're on mobile, see image below), the 9's tail goes below, and the 6's head goes above.

What is it called (I wasn't able to find out), and is there a historic reason behind this style?

---

[image]

Comment: I know the style you're referring to, but in the example you've shown all of the digits are the same height.

Comment: @nnnnnn: It's showing correctly here, are on mobile? I'll make a screenshot in case it doesn't render the same for everyone.

Comment: I am reading this on a mobile yes. Screenshot would be great, thanks.

Comment: The historic reason is handwriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com),

**[Oldstyle Figures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures)**:

> Oldstyle figures (also known as *non-lining*, *lowercase*, *hanging*, or *text* figures) have varying heights and alignments, as opposed to lining figures, which are of uniform height and alignment. Oldstyle figures are similar to lowercase characters in that they share the same x-height and have ascenders (the 6 and 8) and descenders (the 3, 4, 5, 7 and 9).

See also **Typography Deconstructed**:
[Old-Style Figures](https://typedecon.com/blogs/type-glossary/old-style-figures/):

> Style of Arabic Numerals where the characters appear at different positions and heights as opposed to the modern style of all numerals at the same size and position are called Old Style Figures. Some Old Style figures sit entirely above the baseline while others (such as the tail on the numeral 9) descend below the baseline. Often Old Style Figures are available only in Expert Character Sets although some fonts may come with both Old Style Figures and Lining Figures (those that sit on the baseline).  Also Known As: ornamental figures, old style numerals, non-lining

And **Wikipedia**:
[Text Figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures):

> **Text figures** (also known as **non-lining**, **lowercase**, **old style**, **ranging**, **hanging**, **medieval**, **billing**, or **antique** figures or numerals) are numerals typeset with varying heights in a fashion that resembles a typical line of running text, hence the name.Georgia is an example of a popular typeface that employs text figures by default.
>   Remember to also see the [Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures#Design) and [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures#History) sections for more details.

HTH.

Comment: *RE are similar to lowercase characters:* I'm not sure I understand this part. Take "i" for example, or "a", what are their ascenders and descenders?

Comment: @MVUNo.369255 - Not every lowercase letter has ascenders and descenders, but as a group lowercase letters have both.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Like a "g"? What is an example of a lower-case letter with an ascender?

Comment: @MVUNo.369255: https://typedecon.com/blogs/type-glossary/ascender ; https://typedecon.com/blogs/type-glossary/descender 
The **6** has an ascender and the **9** a descender.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks, it does help. There's a history section on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I've included your reference in the answer.